# A consequence of the Lipschitz inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lipschitz-functions

Is the following true?

If $F : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is Lipschitz  then there exists $L'$ such that for every $x \in\mathbb R$ 
$$|F(x)| \le L'(1+|x|)$$

Comment: Do you have some other assumptions, like $|F(0)|\leq L$ or that $F(x)=0$ for some $|x|\leq1$?

Comment: actually is what i'm tryn to understand...i think the note it's wrong too. Thank you

Comment: @ Joonas , no...only f continuous and lip.  defined all over R

Comment: i think i've understood the position of the problem; it's sayng...but it wasn't so clear...if F is lip with const= L then exist an L" such that |F(x)|=<L"(1+|x|) thank you!

Comment: I edited the question to correct the statement based on your comment. Also, see [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

Note that 
$$|f(x)|\leqslant |f(x)-f(0)| +|f(0)| \leqslant|x|\cdot\sup_{u<v}\frac{|f(v)-f(u) |}{v-u}  +|f(0)| \leqslant L'(1+|x|),$$
where 
$$L':=\max\left\{\sup_{u<v}\frac{|f(v)-f(u) |}{v-u},|f(0)| \right\}.$$